# Fantasy novel about a girl who can communicate with animals

Tags: story-identification, novel

In the novel, certain people are born with special abilities that are unique to each individual. The protagonist is trying to protect her brother who, iirc, has the ability to compel people to obey him, but that's not revealed until the end. At one point, they're taken captive by a group trying to gather these special people together and, in order to escape, the girl makes all the microscopic gnits on one of the captor's skin bite him over and over. At one point they escape to a castle where the boy bonds with a maid who he takes under his control. I think the cover art was the two of them standing in front of the gate to the castle, but I'm far less sure of that. I probably read it back in the late 90's or early 00's.

Comment: Can she ♫♫ *Grunt and Squeak aaaaand Squawk with the animals* ♫♫?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*The Secret of Dragonhome*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/764640.The_Secret_of_Dragonhome) by John Peel.

> Melayne and her young brother Sarrow are Talents, hunted by the King's
> relentless Seekers. If their Talent is discovered, they will be sent
> to their death. So they must hide...or die.
>
> Melayne and Sarrow find refuge at Dragonhome, the mysterious estate of
> the shadowy Lord Sander. Lord Sander also has something to hide--a
> dark and fantastical secret that haunts his every move. In order to
> save herself and her brother, Melayne must confront forces much
> stronger than her talent--tempests of magic, desire, and betrayal. If
> Melayne is not careful, her truth will be revealed. Melayne must
> unlock the secrets of Dragonhome. As danger approaches, it will be her
> only hope.
>
> [image]

Comment: Yes! Yes, this is it! Thank you!